# Outlook 2007 to 2010 upgrade - Invisible folders issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook, upgrade, microsoft-outlook-2010

I upgraded my outlook 2007 to 2010. Everything was smooth, but realised later that, some of the archeive folders are missing.

But, When I did a search on my archeive for a mail(exists in missing folder), it is able to show the mail in the search results. It is also showing the missing folder name in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why some folders are hidden from the Mail category in the Navigation Pane. But you can access all your folders by selecting "Folder List" at the bottom of the Navigation Pane. The shortcut is Ctrl+6.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were trying to see default e-mail folders that were hidden. Not only were they hidden, they were unsubscribed at the Gmail server.

Go to Folders tab → Purge → Purge options → More Folders Button → Select Gmail / Spam. Uncheck "Always show subscribed folders in hierarchy of folders".

In Outlook 2010, click Apply and OK.

Restart Outlook 2010 and check and hopefully you'll find the missing folder(s) there with all e-mails (in this situation the Spam folder and Sent folder were original missing).